# Getting the SQL statement which is going to be executed by Oracle trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

Is there any way that I can get the SQL statement which is going to be executed from inside an Oracle trigger, for example in before update trigger for table a I got update a set x=y

Comment: I really don't think so. I think you might have more luck starting a new question with what your problem is, maybe there's a different solution.

Comment: I need to have a log of all transactions to send to a remote server later

Comment: Is this any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805181/oracle-trigger-log

Comment: What is the remote server going to do with that log?  Are you trying to replicate changes?  If so, why not use one of the various replication technologies that Oracle provides (materialized views, Streams, standby databases, GoldenGate, etc.)?  Are you trying to audit changes?  If so, why do you care about the SQL statement rather than the before and after data values?  Depending on the requirements, you may want to look at fine-grained auditing but it's hard to recommend that without knowing what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, don't use a trigger.

Instead, create a Fine Grained Audit (FGA) policy on that table that will cover any DML.

Within the FGA's policy handler, you can access

```
SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','CURRENT_SQL')
```

But you have to use something like FGA or else that will be `null`.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE matt_a (a NUMBER);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE matt_fga_handler IS
  PROCEDURE handle_it (schema_name VARCHAR2, table_name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2);
END matt_fga_handler;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY matt_fga_handler IS
  PROCEDURE handle_it (schema_name VARCHAR2, table_name VARCHAR2, policy_name VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('SQL was: ' || SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','CURRENT_SQL'));
  END;
END matt_fga_handler;


--BEGIN
--  DBMS_FGA.DROP_POLICY('APPS','MATT_A','MY_NEW_POLICY');
--END;

BEGIN
  DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY(
    object_schema => 'APPS',
      object_name => 'MATT_A',
      policy_name => 'MY_NEW_POLICY',
      audit_condition => '1=1',
      audit_column => 'A',
      handler_schema => 'APPS',
      handler_module => 'MATT_FGA_HANDLER.handle_it',
      enable => true,
      statement_types => 'INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT'
    );
END;

-- Run this to test it (make sure SERVEROUT is ON to see the results!)
insert into matt_a (a) SELECT rownum FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 15;
```